# What "Site URL" do I use for Facebook OmniAuth for a local environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

I need to test the omniauth-facebook authentication from my local application. However, the Facebook Developer website is asking for the `Site URL` and I'm not sure what to put for a local development URL to get the proper callback.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `http://localhost:3000/` as the site url on the Facebook Developers site and it will work just fine with OmniAuth.

Comment: Glad to help!  If it helped you solved the problem, please hit the checkmark next to the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test on local host and keep your production environment working:

1- Create a new Facebook app only for development purposes

2- Set the Site URL field to: `http://localhost:3000/`

3- Then edit your /config/initializers/omniauth.rb file to match the following:

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  if Rails.env.development?
    OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    provider :facebook, 'DEV_APP_ID', 'DEV_APP_SEVRET'
  else
    provider :facebook, 'DEPLOY_APP_ID', 'DEPLOY_APP_SECRET'
  end
end
```

Then relaunch `rails server` and you should be able to login through your new app.